# Problem with sections and images

Tags: graphics, compiling, linux

I'm writing a report using the IFAC style, but when making some sections and putting some images inside in the following way:

```
 \section{Section 1}

    \subsection{Subsection 1}

    One thing and other
   \begin{figure}[H]
   \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=8.4cm]{file1.png} 
   \caption{caption } 
   \label{fig:LM741}
   \end{center}
   \end{figure}


\subsection{Subsection 2}
```

after compiling it to PDF, instead of the images inside each subsection, it gets the list of sections/subsection and the whole bunch of images at the end.
How to correct this?

P.S.: I have tried using sections and subsection.

Comment: have you defined the `H` float type? in latex prior to 2015 using H would take all figures to the end. with more recent latex it will give an error.

Comment: Try h! instead of H (see above comment)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not define the type, in fact I do not know about the issue, hope you can point a article or web to get more info.

Comment: @aidangallagher4 Trying now...

Comment: H is provided by the float package. (but if your latex is older than 2015 you should probably update your tex system)

Comment: Ok! That solve the problem, thanks, but I would to like more about this details.

Comment: @aidangallagher4 `[htp]` is a lot better than `[h]` (omitting p makes it far more likely that the figure goes to end of document)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, not it is not, Im using  Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)

Comment: @riccs_0x somewhere you must have seen some documentation or example using `H` (as it is not mentioned in any of the official latex documentation) that documentation must have mentioned the `float` package that defines that option.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle doesnt the exclamation mark override all the other parameters anyway? I suppose if there OP wanted some flexability about where it ended up then htp is better though fair enough

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perhaps read it a long time a go, so its better to say that perhaps I forgot that, But im looking for [htp] right now

Comment: In that case you should have got an error: `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  
\end{figure}
\end{document}` makes `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option  \`H'.`

Comment: @aidangallagher4 no. `[!h]` means not top not bottom and not float page, normally latex issues a warning and changes it to `!ht` to give itself a chance but it still means not bottom and not float page